# MySQL : SELECT all USERS With 2 messages open and clicked after timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a MySQL script executed in PHP.
So I have 3 tables.

Messages who contains at least 3 000 000 rows
(userid, messageid, timestamp, received, opened, clicked, deliveryid)

Users
(user(unique), profile, profile_actual_timestamp, last_delivery_id_sent)

events_clicked_data who contains at least 2 000 000 rows and detailed clicked event. This user click on this profile(like GAMES) on this message(deliveryId)
(userid, profile, deliveryId, eventDate)

So here is sample data for messages and users tables.

```
CREATE TABLE messages
    (`user_id` varchar(100), `message_id` int, `timestamp` datetime, `received` varchar(5), `opened` varchar(5), `clicked` varchar(5), `delivery_id` int);

INSERT INTO messages
    (`user_id`, `message_id`, `timestamp`, `received`, `opened`, `clicked`, `delivery_id`)
VALUES
    ("BillyStuff", 12,'2016-05-16 00:00:00', 'true', 'true', 'true', 8),
    ("BillyStuff", 11,'2016-05-14 00:00:00', 'true', 'true', 'true' , 7),
    ("BillyStuff", 8,'2016-04-03 00:00:00', 'true', 'false', 'false' , 6),
    ("BillyStuff", 4,'2016-04-02 00:00:00', 'true', 'false', 'false', 5),
    ("JohnDoe", 15 ,'2016-05-16 00:00:00', 'true', 'true', 'false' , 4),
    ("JohnDoe", 13 ,'2016-05-14 00:00:00', 'true', 'true', 'true', 3),
    ("Donnie", 15 ,'2016-05-16 00:00:00', 'true', 'true', 'true' , 4),
    ("Donnie", 13 ,'2016-05-14 00:00:00', 'true', 'true', 'true', 3)

CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` varchar(100), `profile` varchar(100), `profile_actual_timestamp` datetime, `last_delivery_id_sent` int);

INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`, `profile`, `profile_actual_timestamp`, `last_delivery_id_sent`)
VALUES
    ("BillyStuff", "Game", "2016-01-01 00:00:00", 1),
    ("JohnDoe", "Book", "2016-01-01 00:00:00", 1),
    ("Donnie", "Book", "2016-05-16 00:00:00", 4)
```

I want to get users with 2 messages clicked after timestamp (profile_actual_timestamp means last time it was updated) in profile.

In this case I only get BillyStuff because Donnie is already up to date if I check if profile_actual_timestamp.

After this, I need to check by deliveryId and user in events_clicked's table if same categories was clicked.

```
CREATE TABLE events_clicked_data
    (`user_id` varchar(100), `profile` varchar(100), `deliveryId` int, `eventDate` datetime);

INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`, `profile`, `deliveryId`, `eventDate`) VALUES
    ("BillyStuff", "Book", 8,"2016-01-01 00:00:00"),
    ("BillyStuff", "Book", 7,"2016-01-01 00:00:00"),
    ("JohnDoe", "Book", 3,"2016-01-01 00:00:00"),
    ("Donnie", "Book", 4,"2016-05-16 00:00:00"),
    ("Donnie", "Game", 3,"2016-05-16 00:00:00")
```

In this case, i need to update BillyStuff's profile and change it to "Book" instead of "Game" because he clicked on the same categorie twice in his last messages after the last time he was updated (profile_actual_timestamp)

So its been a really good puzzle for me this week and Im wondering if you guys can help me with this one.

originalid = userid (not necessary original, depend on table)
e.name = name of profil clicked like game.

```
select  originalid,
        name
from   (
        select  @g := if(@u = originalid, if (@p = name, @g, @g + 1), 1) as grp,
                @u := originalid as originalid,
                @p := name as name
        from   (
                select     u.originalid, 
                           m.message_sendtime_timestamp,
                           e.name
                from       bienvenue_nouveau_client_dev u
                inner join messages_nouveaux_clients m
                        on m.originalid = u.originalid
                inner join events_clicked_data e
                        on e.originalId = u.originalid
                       and e.deliveryId = m.deliveryId
                where      m.message_sendtime_timestamp >= u.profil_actuel_timestamp
                and        m.clicked = 'TRUE'
                limit      1000000000000000
                order by   u.originalid,
                           m.message_sendtime_timestamp desc
               ) alias
        ) alias2
where    grp = 1
group by originalid, name
having   count(*) > 1
```

Whatever I change I got an error like this:

## 1250 - Table 'u' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Comment: *After this, I need to check by deliveryId and user*: do you have two questions? Or do you mean with *after this* just a notion of sequence to get the desired result?

Comment: Just a notion of sequence. I'm focusing to get users at first. I might do the second step in PHP (or not).

Comment: There is the `messages.timestamp` and the `events_clicked_data.eventDate`: what is the difference in meaning, and is the second date used in your requirements?

Comment: No, this date is not used because I can get the events clicked only with user and deliveryId.

Comment: You have `deliveryId` in both `users` table and `messages` table. Which of the two should be used to find `events_clicked_data`? Can you provide the primary and foreign keys of your model?

Comment: You should use deliveryId from messages. In user its just the last deliveryId used to update like profile_actual_timestamp

Comment: What if BillyStuff had clicked on "Book", "Game", "Book", "Game", "Book" since last update? Can you be precise on what you want the outcome to be in this case, but also generally, given that you might have a whole range of data since last update, and in any order?

Comment: Exactly last 2 emails received have been clicked and are the same category. And now he will be updated. User timestamp and user delivery are only update if conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

The first query can be done as follows:

```
select     u.*
from       users u
inner join messages m
        on m.user_id = u.user_id
where      m.timestamp >= u.profile_actual_timestamp
and        m.clicked = 'true'
group by   u.user_id
having     count(m.message_id) > 1
```

This second query will give you the users that used the same profile in their last two click events, if these events happened both later than the last update:

```
select  user_id,
        profile
from    (
        select  @g := 0 + if(@u = user_id, if (@p = profile, @g, @g + 1), 1) as grp,
                @u := user_id as user_id,
                @p := profile as profile  
        from    (
                select     u.user_id, 
                           m.timestamp,
                           e.profile
                from       users u
                inner join messages m
                        on m.user_id = u.user_id
                left join  events_clicked_data e
                        on e.user_id = u.user_id
                       and e.deliveryId = m.delivery_id
                where      m.timestamp >= u.profile_actual_timestamp
                order by   u.user_id,
                           m.timestamp desc
                ) alias
        ) alias2
where grp = 1
group by user_id, profile
having  count(*) > 1
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b1a0f/1)

This query depends on variables, and is a bit risky, in that it must return the innermost results in the specified order, and that it must evaluate the middle select list (with variable assignments) in top-to-bottom order. This happens consistently, but in theory it is not guaranteed.

The (high) `limit` in the inner query is there to make sure the `order by` clause is applied, not to actually limit anything.

The variables @u and @p track the *user_id* and *profile*. Based on their previous values, the variable @g is calculated: it is reset to 1 whenever the *user_id* changed. Otherwise it is kept at the same value if also the *profile* didn't change, and it is incremented when the profile did change.

This way the *grp* values identify groups in which the profile is the same and uninterrupted in order of descending timestamp. The most recent group per used has number 1, which is the only one of interest in the outer query. The outer query then requires that this group 1 has more than one record (i.e. more than one occurrence of the same profile).

Comment: its working great on fiddle indeed. But I keep getting this error, whatever I do. #1250 - Table 'u' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause. Ill update my OP with my query.

Comment: You would get that error if you had defined the `u` alias for a table that is in a sub-select, but this is not the case in the query I have proposed. Also, it is not the case in the query you have added to your question. I suppose your actual query looks different, and performs another sub-query. Or maybe you added an outer `order by` that references `u`. I don't know because when I try *your* query, I don't get that error.

Comment: Im using the same query. It might be because my version is 5.5.44-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: Do you issue the query via the MariaDB tools, or via an application?

Comment: On phpmyadmin. If i user alias2.user_id alias2.profile in group by I got something but still without the limit clause.

Comment: That really sounds like a particular behaviour that is different in MySql from MariaDB, although they should essentially work with the same syntax. The `limit` clause is not really mandatory, it is just a safeguard that might not be necessary. Check if the result is OK without it.

Comment: You could also check if there is a maximum to what you can specify for `limit`. For MySql the number I put is no problem, but maybe for MariaDB  it has to be smaller.

Comment: Ok, query is working without limit but doesnt give right answer. Here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cd62/1 I shouldnt get Billy because he didnt clicked on last 2 messages as you can see.

Comment: OK, that is different from what I understood from the question. I have updated my answer, with updated fiddle, where I have modified Diana's data, so there is a result for that person. I understand from your last comment that non-click messages are an interruption to a series of click messages, so now that table is *outer* joined and the `click = true` condition is removed. Now the profile will be `null` when `click = false` and so it will increment the grp variable, which may lead to grp 1 not having 2 records. Please let me know if with smaller limit it would work with the limit clause.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back whether the update I mentioned in my previous comment answered your question?